# What are the corresponding ant javac options for Eclipse compiler settings?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm trying to get an ant build file to generate identical class files as the eclipse compiler

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
```

The first three of which correspond (I hope!) to `debuglevel="vars,lines,source"` in the javac task:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"  debug="true"  debuglevel="vars,lines,source" target="1.5" >
   <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
</javac>
```

What about the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first three, I think all you need to tell Ant javac is `debug="true"`. You will get vars, lines and source by default. Specifying them explicitly is fine too.

For the last, this is particular to the Eclipse JDT compiler. I don't think other compilers optimize unused local variables away. Certainly, I've never been caught with debugger out of step due to removed unused local variables.

Are you using the JDT compiler in your Ant build [using the Ant javac adapter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-ant_javac_adapter.htm)? Unless you do, I don't think you can guarantee absolutely identical class files between the two environments. However, I would be a bit suspicious of a requirement to have such a level identical-ness.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to generate an ear using jenkins which is as close as possible to the ear we generate from eclipse using Export->EAR. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091753/class-cast-exceptions-with-ant-jenkins-generated-ear-on-websphere-6-1

Comment: I've responded on that question. I would suspect classpath rather than compiler issue.

Comment: There is no particular requirement for identical class files, just trying to eliminate differences in the compilation process. BTW, updated the other question.